# How to compress data when using psql's copy statement?

Tags: postgresql, copy, gzip, psql

My goal is to efficiently import large amounts of data into a Postgres Database. In principle, the raw data could be compressed by a factor of ~20 (e.g. using gzip).

The `COPY` statement seems to be the best option for a bulk import.

Apart from sslcompression (which is applied after the data is encrypted), is there a way to compress the actual data (content) transferred between client and server, or is that even built-in by default?

Many thanks.

(Should not matter, but I am using golang).

Comment: The data is going to have to be uncompressed before the server can use it, assuming you are not storing the data in binary form in its compressed state. To me the solution would be to compress the data on the client machine transfer it to the server machine and then uncompress to load into server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bottleneck is network throughput, you will want to send (copy or stream) compressed data to the database machine using something like scp or ssh, then run COPY in a client on the same machine as the database server is running.  There are a number of ways this can be orchestrated, but all of them have something other than libpq/PostgreSQL as the conductor of the orchestra.

Answer (score 5):

the `COPY [TO|FROM] PROGRAM` allows to use gzip as a program, if it is installed somewhere accessible to the postgres server process: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.10.

You could also use `COPY TO|FROM STDIN` and do the de/compression client-side.

Comment: The synopsis suggests that `PROGRAM 'command'` and `STDIN` can only be used exclusively. As far as my understanding goes, this means I CANNOT read gzipped data from `STDIN`, pipe it through the gzip program, and into a table from there. The gzipped data needs to be present on the server. Correct?

Comment: only  the programs to be executed by `PROGRAM` need to be present on the server. You could use `copy from program 'curl SOME_URL.zip | gunzip'` or something like that

Comment: yes `PROGRAM` is also passing the output to stdin, which implies STDIN. And indeed, postgres doesn't understand gzip content, it has to be passed uncompressed (be it textual or binary), but you can do the decompression very near the server process with `copy from program`, which can be better than sending it decompressed from the client